# passing a model int as a parameter in method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test and i wrote a method to pass in parameters for testing. one of my ids are an integer but of a different type. Here is what i have:

Service layer:

```
public IEnumerable<IElement> GetType(int id, int userId, ElementType type, int depth = 2)
    {
        using (var db = database.connection)
        {

            var _results = db.table<_ElementBase>(id, userId, type.ModelId, IElementExtensions.IElementFactory(), depthLevel: depth);
            return _results.FilterByPermissions(userId);
        }
    }
```

ElementType Model:

```
public int ModelId { get; set; }
```

Unit Test code to test:

```
 var _elements = _elementSvc.GetType(82,1,10,2);
```

Here it is not likeing the (10) and it wants ElementType

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes - look at your parameter list:

```
GetType(int id, int userId, ElementType type, int depth = 2)
```

How are you *expecting* the third argument (10) to be converted into an `ElementType`? And how would you expect a `ModelId` to be extracted from that?

You should either change `GetType` to just take the `modelId` directly:

```
public IEnumerable<IElement> GetType(int id, int userId, int modelId, int depth = 2)
{
    using (var db = database.connection)
    {
        var _results = db.table<_ElementBase>(id, userId, modelId, 
                 IElementExtensions.IElementFactory(), depthLevel: depth);
        return _results.FilterByPermissions(userId);
    }
}
```

You could then overload the method if you still wanted the original signature as well:

```
public IEnumerable<IElement> GetType(int id, int userId, ElementType type,
                                     int depth = 2)
{
    return GetType(id, userId, type.ModelId, depth);
}
```